# CURL Request on form which don't have submit button

Tags: php, forms, curl

Today, I'm trying to make a CURL request on a non-well coded website.
The form is composed by 2 fields and a `<a>`button which trigger a JavaScript function who force the form submit.

My first question : Is a CURL request can be made with this type of form ? 
If yes, is my code seems to be good ?

```
$postfields = array(
    'login' => 'test',
    'password' => 'test'
);
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('HeaderName: HeaderValue'));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
$return = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Thanks guys

Comment: Just put it online on test server and check for yourself if it works, not exactly a good questions for SO

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript function is likely doing the following thing:

```
document.getElementById('form').submit();
```

Which has exactly the same behavior thing than pressing a *submit* button. So yes, your script is likely to work. Don't hesitate to try it by yourself before asking on SO, next time :-)

Comment: I'm understanding this way but Is the CURL Request will submit form even if is there is no submit form ?

Comment: "Submitting a form" is just doing a HTTP request with one or more parameters, and CURL is HTTP client. There is no notion of form submission for him.